# Quiz app + singleton classes as3

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, singleton

I've a problem with the radiobuttons because when I delete the instance from the stage where the radiobuttons are, if I create again the instance the radiobuttons keeps the last selection.

( I've written the class in spanish, if you've problems to identify the concept, please ask me )

Class ( crearPregunta.as or askQuestion.as )

```
package src.com.akkadian
```

{

```
import fl.controls.RadioButtonGroup;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.xml.*;
import src.com.akkadian.manipularXML;

public class crearPregunta extends MovieClip
{

    private static var _instance:crearPregunta = null;

    private var xmlPath:String;
    private var radioGroup1:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup("Questions");
    private var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    private var instanciaXML:manipularXML;
    protected var time:Timer;
    private var rs:String;
    private var resp:XMLList;
    private var re:XMLList;
    private var pre:XMLList;
    private var opSeleccionada:Number;
    private var resultado:Boolean = false;

    public function crearPregunta()
    {


    }

    public static function getInstance():crearPregunta
    {

        if (_instance == null)
        {

            _instance = new crearPregunta();

        }

        return _instance;
    }

    private function generarContenido()
    {

        // Crea the XML instance from manipularXML class
        this.instanciaXML = manipularXML.generarInstancia();

        // Send the path of the file
        this.xmlPath = "src/com/akkadian/preguntas.xml";

        // Add the listener to proceed when the load is finished        
        xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, inXML);
        xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(this.xmlPath));

        // adding a listener to the button sendResponse
        enviarRespuesta.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, recibirRespuesta);
        enviarRespuesta.buttonMode = true;

    }

    public function validarRespuesta(opcionSeleccionada:String):Boolean
    {
        // Option chosen
        opSeleccionada = Number(opcionSeleccionada);

        // Generate the content
        generarContenido();

        // Send the result
        return resultado;
    }

    private function inXML(e:Event):void
    {
        // Add the radiobuttons to an Array
        var radios:Array = [casoA, casoB, casoC];

        // Obtain the data from the XML
        var data = instanciaXML.obtenerInfo(e.target.data);


        for each (var nodo:XML in data.pregunta)
        {

            if (nodo.@id == opSeleccionada)
            {
                // Keep the answer for the option chosen
                resp = data.pregunta[opSeleccionada - 1].respuesta;

                // Keep the value for the option chosen
                re = data.pregunta[opSeleccionada - 1].respuesta.@valor;

                // Keep the question
                pre = data.pregunta[opSeleccionada - 1].@pre

                // add the value of the question to the dinamic textfield
                question.text = pre;

                for (var u:uint = 0; u < radios.length; u++)
                {

                    radios[u].group = radioGroup1;
                    radios[u].textField.multiline = true;
                    radios[u].textField.wordWrap = true;
                    radios[u].textField.width = 230;
                    radios[u].textField.height = 100;
                    radios[u].textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;


                    // Add the answers to the labels
                    radios[u].label = resp[u];

                    // Add the answers to the values
                    radios[u].value = re[u];

                }

            }

        }
    }

    private function recibirRespuesta(m:MouseEvent)
    {

        for each (var tre:XML in re)
        {
            // if the value of the answer is equal to the value stored
            if (this.radioGroup1.selection.value == re)
            {
                // Save the result as true
                this.resultado = true;

                // Add the value of the answer to the textfield included on this Instance
                result_txt.text = "Correcto";
            }
            else
            {
                // Save the result as false
                this.resultado = false;

                // Add the value of the answer to the textfield included on this Instance
                result_txt.text = "Incorrecto";
            }
        }

        // Add a function to create a timer
        agregarTimer();

    }

    private function agregarTimer()
    {
        // Setup the timer
        time = new Timer(1000, 1);
        time.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, cerrarTimer);
        time.start();

    }

    private function cerrarTimer(t:TimerEvent)
    {
        // Just for information, I verify which are the instances that at present ran in the Main instance
        Main.Instancia.obtenerNombreHijos();

        // Remove the instance askQuestion from the Main
        Main.Instancia.removeChildAt(2);

        // I certify that the instance is deleted
        Main.Instancia.obtenerNombreHijos();

        // I change the instance of the xml class to null
        instanciaXML = null;


    }

}
```

}

Result: What is happening now?

1. The user run the trivia: first, select the start option ( the grid of options is created )
2. The user choose one option ( askQuestion instance is created )
3. When the user select the option from the radiobuttons ( the result is displayed on the result_txt.text )
4. The timer is executed
5. Remove the instance ( askQuestion ) from the Main class
6. IF the user select another option, the question and the answers are displayed correctly but, the radiobutton keep the option selected before and the result_txt.text shows the the result of this selection.. this is wrong because, no selection must be done.

---

**I've another situation from this.. I've this:
static instance a  ( here is created the instance c  )
static instance b ( here the result of the operation. This instance will be removed when the result is obtained )
instance c ( result is display )
How can I do to send information from instance b to instance c inf the instance was created in instance a**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is you're re-using the same radio button group each time, but you don't reset the selectedIndex or selectedValue of that radio button group.  I believe this would fix the problem:

```
            radioGroup1.selectedIndex=-1;
            for (var u:uint = 0; u < radios.length; u++)
            {

                radios[u].group = radioGroup1;
                radios[u].textField.multiline = true;
                radios[u].textField.wordWrap = true;
                radios[u].textField.width = 230;
                radios[u].textField.height = 100;
                radios[u].textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;


                // Add the answers to the labels
                radios[u].label = resp[u];

                // Add the answers to the values
                radios[u].value = re[u];

            }
```

Comment: I've another situation from this.. I've this: static instance a ( here is created the instance c ) static instance b ( here the result of the operation. This instance will be removed when the result is obtained ) instance c ( result is display ) How can I do to send information from instance b to instance c inf the instance was created in instance a

Comment: If this resolves your original issue of the radio button re-selecting you should accept it and post your new issue as it's own question.  The goal on SO is not for people to help you complete your project, the goal is to have a repository of questions and answers that can benefit everyone.  If things aren't kept piecemeal they aren't as useful.

Answer (score 1):

To delete something in Flash, or in other words ready it up for Garbage Collector try removing all the listeners from the object, removing it from stage and then setting it to null.